# For loop inside for loops java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to get a for loop inside a for loop so that the output is like this:

I wan the output to show a square

I'm not sure why it isn't doing it.
Below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give me a number : ");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = kb.nextInt();
        for(int i2=i;i2<i+i;i2++) {
            System.out.print("x");
            for( i2=i;i2<i+i;i2++) {
                System.out.println("x");    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The system.out.println should be on the outside print. Not the inside print. Also i2 is getting modified by the inner for loop. use a different variable for the control variable for the inner for loop

Comment: Each loop should have its own counter, your inner loop is using `i2` which is also used by your outer loop.

Comment: You should be closing the `Scanner` as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to have separate variables for each of the loops. Otherwise, you'll never run the second iteration of the outer loop. When you're done the inside, your `i2` is at the max of the condition of your outer.

Also, you only need the `System.out.print()` on the inner loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print("x");
    }
    // When you're done printing the "x"s for the row, start a new row.
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same loop counter for both loops, `i2`. So, when your inner loop executes, you are increasing the value of `i2` by 1. This continues until `i2` gets to your designated stop point. Then the inner loop ends. It then returns to the outer loop, and the outer loop checks if `i2` is past the stop point. Since you increased the value of `i2` in the inner loop, it is already past the cutoff point, and the outer loop stops.

To fix this, use separate variables for each loop. See below. I use `i` for the outer loop, `j` for the inner loop, and `number` as the cutoff point.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int number = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.out.println("Give me a number : ");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = kb.nextInt();
    int height = size;
    int width = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            System.out.print("X");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```